# " ArityMismatch: Adding expressions with non-matching form arguments () vs ('v_1',) " using FEniCS

Tags: python-3.x, fenics

I want to solve a continuum mechanics problem thanks to FEniCS. I apply pressure and take into account the weight. But when I add the thermoelasticity component, it doesn't work anymore.
Here is my code :

```
from dolfin import *
from fenics import *
from ufl import nabla_div
from ufl import as_tensor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

E = Constant(100*10**9)
nu = Constant(0.3)
Lg = 0.01; W = 0.2
mu = E/(2+2*nu)
rho = Constant(2200)
delta = W/Lg
gamma = 0.4*delta**2
beta = 8
lambda_ = (E*nu)/((1+nu)*(1-2*nu))
alpha = 1.2*(10**(-8))
deltaT = Constant(50)
Kt = E*alph*deltaT/(1-2*nu)
g = 9.81
tol = 1E-14

# Create mesh and define function space
mesh = RectangleMesh(Point(-2., 0.),Point(2., 10.), 80, 200)
V = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "P", 1)
# Define boundary condition

def clamped_boundary(x, on_boundary):
    return on_boundary and x[1] < tol

class UpFace(SubDomain):
    def inside(self, x, on_boundary):
        return on_boundary and (x[1] > 10 - tol)

ueN = UpFace()
boundaries = MeshFunction("size_t", mesh, mesh.topology().dim()-1, 0)
ueN.mark(boundaries, 1)
ds = Measure("ds", domain=mesh, subdomain_data=boundaries)


bc = DirichletBC(V, Constant((0, 0)), clamped_boundary)

def epsilon(u):
    return 0.5*(nabla_grad(u) + nabla_grad(u).T)
def sigma(u):
    return (lambda_*nabla_div(u) - Kt)*Identity(d) + (2*mu)*epsilon(u) 

# Define variational problem
u = TrialFunction(V)
d = u.geometric_dimension() # space dimension
v = TestFunction(V)
f = Constant((0,-rho*g))
T = Constant((0, 0))
Pr = Constant((0, -2*10**9))
a = inner(sigma(u), epsilon(v))*dx
L = dot(f, v)*dx + dot(T, v)*ds + dot(Pr,v)*ds(1)

# Compute solution
u = Function(V)
solve(a == L, u, bc)

# Plot solution
plot(u, mode="displacement", color= "red")
plt.colorbar(plot(u))
```

I get this error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArityMismatch                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-805d7c5b704f> in <module>
     17 # Compute solution
     18 u = Function(V)
---> 19 solve(a == L, u, bc)
     20 
     21 # Plot solution

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/fem/solving.py in solve(*args, **kwargs)
    218     # tolerance)
    219     elif isinstance(args[0], ufl.classes.Equation):
--> 220         _solve_varproblem(*args, **kwargs)
    221 
    222     # Default case, just call the wrapped C++ solve function

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/fem/solving.py in _solve_varproblem(*args, **kwargs)
    240         # Create problem
    241         problem = LinearVariationalProblem(eq.lhs, eq.rhs, u, bcs,
--> 242                                            form_compiler_parameters=form_compiler_parameters)
    243 
    244         # Create solver and call solve

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/fem/problem.py in __init__(self, a, L, u, bcs, form_compiler_parameters)
     54         else:
     55             L = Form(L, form_compiler_parameters=form_compiler_parameters)
---> 56         a = Form(a, form_compiler_parameters=form_compiler_parameters)
     57 
     58         # Initialize C++ base class

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/fem/form.py in __init__(self, form, **kwargs)
     42 
     43         ufc_form = ffc_jit(form, form_compiler_parameters=form_compiler_parameters,
---> 44                            mpi_comm=mesh.mpi_comm())
     45         ufc_form = cpp.fem.make_ufc_form(ufc_form[0])
     46 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/jit/jit.py in mpi_jit(*args, **kwargs)
     45         # Just call JIT compiler when running in serial
     46         if MPI.size(mpi_comm) == 1:
---> 47             return local_jit(*args, **kwargs)
     48 
     49         # Default status (0 == ok, 1 == fail)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dolfin/jit/jit.py in ffc_jit(ufl_form, form_compiler_parameters)
     95     p.update(dict(parameters["form_compiler"]))
     96     p.update(form_compiler_parameters or {})
---> 97     return ffc.jit(ufl_form, parameters=p)
     98 
     99 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/jitcompiler.py in jit(ufl_object, parameters, indirect)
    215 
    216     # Inspect cache and generate+build if necessary
--> 217     module = jit_build(ufl_object, module_name, parameters)
    218 
    219     # Raise exception on failure to build or import module

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/jitcompiler.py in jit_build(ufl_object, module_name, parameters)
    131                                     name=module_name,
    132                                     params=params,
--> 133                                     generate=jit_generate)
    134     return module
    135 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dijitso/jit.py in jit(jitable, name, params, generate, send, receive, wait)
    163         elif generate:
    164             # 1) Generate source code
--> 165             header, source, dependencies = generate(jitable, name, signature, params["generator"])
    166             # Ensure we got unicode from generate
    167             header = as_unicode(header)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/jitcompiler.py in jit_generate(ufl_object, module_name, signature, parameters)
     64 
     65     code_h, code_c, dependent_ufl_objects = compile_object(ufl_object,
---> 66             prefix=module_name, parameters=parameters, jit=True)
     67 
     68     # Jit compile dependent objects separately,

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/compiler.py in compile_form(forms, object_names, prefix, parameters, jit)
    141     """This function generates UFC code for a given UFL form or list of UFL forms."""
    142     return compile_ufl_objects(forms, "form", object_names,
--> 143                                prefix, parameters, jit)
    144 
    145 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/compiler.py in compile_ufl_objects(ufl_objects, kind, object_names, prefix, parameters, jit)
    183     # Stage 1: analysis
    184     cpu_time = time()
--> 185     analysis = analyze_ufl_objects(ufl_objects, kind, parameters)
    186     _print_timing(1, time() - cpu_time)
    187 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/analysis.py in analyze_ufl_objects(ufl_objects, kind, parameters)
     88         # Analyze forms
     89         form_datas = tuple(_analyze_form(form, parameters)
---> 90                            for form in forms)
     91 
     92         # Extract unique elements accross all forms

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/analysis.py in <genexpr>(.0)
     88         # Analyze forms
     89         form_datas = tuple(_analyze_form(form, parameters)
---> 90                            for form in forms)
     91 
     92         # Extract unique elements accross all forms

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ffc/analysis.py in _analyze_form(form, parameters)
    172                                       do_apply_geometry_lowering=True,
    173                                       preserve_geometry_types=(Jacobian,),
--> 174                                       do_apply_restrictions=True)
    175     elif r == "tsfc":
    176         try:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufl/algorithms/compute_form_data.py in compute_form_data(form, do_apply_function_pullbacks, do_apply_integral_scaling, do_apply_geometry_lowering, preserve_geometry_types, do_apply_default_restrictions, do_apply_restrictions, do_estimate_degrees, do_append_everywhere_integrals, complex_mode)
    416         preprocessed_form = remove_complex_nodes(preprocessed_form)
    417 
--> 418     check_form_arity(preprocessed_form, self.original_form.arguments(), complex_mode)  # Currently testing how fast this is
    419 
    420     # TODO: This member is used by unit tests, change the tests to

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufl/algorithms/check_arities.py in check_form_arity(form, arguments, complex_mode)
    175 def check_form_arity(form, arguments, complex_mode=False):
    176     for itg in form.integrals():
--> 177         check_integrand_arity(itg.integrand(), arguments, complex_mode)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufl/algorithms/check_arities.py in check_integrand_arity(expr, arguments, complex_mode)
    157                              key=lambda x: (x.number(), x.part())))
    158     rules = ArityChecker(arguments)
--> 159     arg_tuples = map_expr_dag(rules, expr, compress=False)
    160     args = tuple(a[0] for a in arg_tuples)
    161     if args != arguments:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufl/corealg/map_dag.py in map_expr_dag(function, expression, compress)
     35     Return the result of the final function call.
     36     """
---> 37     result, = map_expr_dags(function, [expression], compress=compress)
     38     return result
     39 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufl/corealg/map_dag.py in map_expr_dags(function, expressions, compress)
     84                 r = handlers[v._ufl_typecode_](v)
     85             else:
---> 86                 r = handlers[v._ufl_typecode_](v, *[vcache[u] for u in v.ufl_operands])
     87 
     88             # Optionally check if r is in rcache, a memory optimization

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufl/algorithms/check_arities.py in sum(self, o, a, b)
     46     def sum(self, o, a, b):
     47         if a != b:
---> 48             raise ArityMismatch("Adding expressions with non-matching form arguments {0} vs {1}.".format(_afmt(a), _afmt(b)))
     49         return a
     50 

ArityMismatch: Adding expressions with non-matching form arguments () vs ('v_1',).
```

When I write this (I remove the Kt from sigma(u)):

```
def sigma(u):
    return (lambda_*nabla_div(u))*Identity(d) + (2*mu)*epsilon(u)
```

It works perfectly. 
In this page (Click [here](https://comet-fenics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo/thermoelasticity/thermoelasticity.html)), they try to plot the same kind problem and it works on my computer. 
Do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same question and a colleague of mine did figure it out for me. As there is no answer given here, I will try to leave some directions to guide others to the solution. I have not a lot of expertise yet, so please consider that my use of terminology might be a little bit off.

The error of fenics somewhat mislead me into thinking the error is in the definition of the stress term sigma. It is not exactly there. The right handside and the left handside in the solve function are not defined correctly (also shown in the very top of the error code). The term kT*Identity(d) in the stress function sigma, is not dependent on the trialfunction u. It is just multiplied by the testfunction v later (epsilon(v)). Therefore it has to go into the L of the equation of the solver.

Beneath the Link that you shared, the scipt uses the rhs and lhs function to correctly split the equation into a and L.